# Pseudoinverse and norm

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose the m * n matrix A =$
\begin{bmatrix}
    A_1 \\A_2
\end{bmatrix}$ where A1 is a nonsingular square matrix (n*n) and A2 is an arbitrary matrix. Why is $||A^{+}||_2 \leq ||A_1^{-1}||_2$  ?

($A^{+}$ denotes the psuedoinverse)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $A$ has full column-rank, so its singular values are all positive.

Let $\sigma_1(A),\dots,\sigma_n(A)$ denote the singular values of $A$ from largest to smallest.  We note that $\|A\|_2 = \sigma_1(A)$ and $\|A^+\| = 1/\sigma_{n}(A)$.  Similarly, $\|A_1\|^{-1} = 1/\sigma_n(A_1)$.

Thus, your statement amounts to proving that $1/ \sigma_n(A) \leq 1/\sigma_n(A_1)$.  That is, 
$$
\sigma_{n} \left(\begin{bmatrix}
    A_1 \\A_2
\end{bmatrix}\right) \geq \sigma_n(A_1)
$$
It is easy to prove that this is the case using the Rayleigh-Ritz formula formula for the singular value, namely
$$
\sigma_n(M) = \min_{x \neq 0}\frac{\|Mx\|}{\|x\|}
$$
perhaps now you can see why this works.

---

We have
$$
\sigma_{n} \pmatrix{A_1\\ A_2} = \min_{x \neq 0} \frac{\left\|\pmatrix{A_1\\A_2}x\right\|}{\|x\|} \geq
\min_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|A_1x\|}{\|x\|} = \sigma_n(A_1)
$$

Comment: Thanks. I couldnt think of a reason why $\sigma_n(A) \ne \sigma_n(A_1)$ though. Can you explain?

Comment: In general, we have 
$$
\left\|\pmatrix{A_1\\A_2}x\right\| = \left\|\pmatrix{A_1 x\\ A_2 x}\right\| \geq \| A_1 x\|
$$
If you want an example where this inequality is strict, try $A_1 = A_2 = 1$ (so both blocks are $1 \times 1$).

Comment: Can you provide a proof of this inequality?

Comment: Sure:
$$
\left\|\pmatrix{A_1 x\\ A_2 x}\right\|^2 = 
\|A_1x\|^2 + \|A_2x\|^2 \geq \|A_1x\|^2
$$
now take the square root of both sides.

Comment: On a second though. This proves the inequality for the largest singular value. Don't we need to prove it for the nth largest singular value instead?

Comment: @user1559897 this proves it for both.  Note that the norms in the above inequality are *vector norms*, not *matrix norms*.

Comment: So if the norm is taken to be the 2-norm, then it proves the case for the largest singular value. Can you explain how it proves the case for the smallest singular value?

Comment: See my latest edit.  I don't understand how you see that this works for the largest singular value, but fail to see how this works for the smallest singular value.

Comment: $$ \left\|\pmatrix{A_1 x\\ A_2 x}\right\|^2 =  \|A_1x\|^2 + \|A_2x\|^2 \geq \|A_1x\|^2 $$

This is not right, is it? 

$$ \left\|\pmatrix{A_1 x\\ A_2 x}\right\|^2 =  \|A_1x + A_2x\|^2 \leq \|A_1x\|^2 + \| A_2x\|^2$$ 

You Dont have the inequality from line 1, do you?

Comment: The inequality from line 1 is correct. Your version is wrong

Comment: yeah my version is incorrect. i got confused for a moment, but why is line 1 correct though.

Comment: I think if you try an example, you'll see why
$$
\left\|\pmatrix{x\\y}\right\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2
$$
will work for any column vectors $x,y$.

Comment: you mean 2-norm only? I thought you meant it holds for all norms...

Comment: Yes, I mean the 2-norm only.  I just didn't want to write the subscript $2$ every time, and I thought it would be clear from the context.  Of course, the inequality 
$$
\left \| \pmatrix{x\\y}\right\| \geq \|x\|
$$
holds for all $p$-norms, and more generally for all symmetric gauge-norms.

Comment: Now i can follow the whole proof. Thx!  @Omnomnomnom